# SQL SELECT to get the most recently added entries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table which is being updated every second.  I would like to make write a query that pulls the **most recent 20,000 records** (about 6 hours worth, since it's collected every second).

I thought to try:

```
SELECT time_stamp, column2, column3 
FROM myDB.table1 
limit 20000;
```

But the above query pulls the items from the very beginning of when the data was inserted into the table.  I would like the most recent 20000 records.

**What would be the query to pull the most recent records inserted into a table?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
SELECT time_stamp, column2, column3
FROM myDB.table1
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
LIMIT 20000;
```

However, you might find that the query is expensive.  If you have an index on `time_stamp`, you might find this more efficient:

```
SELECT time_stamp, column2, column3
FROM myDB.table1
WHERE time_stamp >= date_sub(now(), interval 6 hours);
```

It is not exactly 20,000 records, but it is the most recent records and it should be faster than sorting all the data.

You can create such an index by doing:

```
create index idx_table1_timestamp on table1(time_stamp);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a go.  I will see how long the query takes and if it is necessary to go by the `time_stamp` index, then I will try that.  I am trying to set this up as a recurring query, so I am not quite sure how I'd adjust the date each day.

Comment: Both of these queries seem to be taking a bit of time to execute, when using my Raspberry Pi as a MySQL Client.  Are there any other methods to make this return records faster?

Comment: Do you have an index on `time_stamp`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by your question. So I am guessing that I do not.  How do I create an index on the time_stamp?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  My table is being written to every second, so I was wondering if I create the index as you mention, if it will negatively effect my table in any way?

Comment: @Gary . . . At one input per second, the index will not add a significant amount of overhead -- depending on how much else is going on.